# Can't reverse table view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I tried to reverse my table view in the view did load method by reversing the arrays but it's not working.  I'm trying to make it so that it sorts the feed from the time it was created from top to bottom. Am I doing it wrong? If so what should I do?

```
class Feed: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var feedBar: UINavigationBar!

var titles = [String]()
var messages = [String]()
var usernames  = [String]()
var types = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.dataSource = self
    messages.reverse()
    titles.reverse()
    usernames.reverse()
    types.reverse()
}

func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("View appeared")

    self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.titles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.types.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    var postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)

                self.titles.append(object["title"] as! String)

                self.usernames.append(object["username"] as! String)

                self.types.append(object["type"] as! String)

                self.table.reloadData()


            }

        }

    })
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedPost", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell

    var post = PFObject(className: "Post")

    if messages.isEmpty == false {
        postCell.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]
    }

    if titles.isEmpty == false {
        postCell.postTtitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    }

    if usernames.isEmpty == false {
        postCell.posterName.setTitle(usernames[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
    }

    if self.types[indexPath.row] == "post1" {
        postCell.sideLeft.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFCFFBD)
        postCell.sideRight.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFCFFBD)

    } else if self.types[indexPath.row] == "post2" {
        postCell.sideLeft.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFFB4AC)
        postCell.sideRight.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFFB4AC)

    } else if self.types[indexPath.row] == "post3" {
        postCell.sideLeft.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFFD5A4)
        postCell.sideRight.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0xFFD5A4)
    }


    postCell.selectionStyle = .None

    postCell.message.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))

    return postCell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return usernames.count
}

}
```

Comment: This stuff may help you, its in Objective C. But you will get idea https://github.com/rcmcastro/whatsapp-ios

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in the view's life cycle the viewDidAppear gets called after your viewDidLoad method. It appears that you try to reload the contents from within your viewDidAppear method, and there you are clearing those arrays which you had reversed earlier in viewDidLoad. This is the reason why you are not seeing any effect. You might want to reverse your arrays there.

Comment: Do you see the arrays getting populated in that postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock?

Comment: Yes I do, I just want it to get populated the other way, like most social media feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing array in `viewDidLoad`, but you append something in `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidAppear` call after `viewDidLoad`. You should reverse array in the end of `viewDidAppear` before call `self.table.reloadData()`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("View appeared")

    self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.titles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.types.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    var postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)

                self.titles.append(object["title"] as! String)

                self.usernames.append(object["username"] as! String)

                self.types.append(object["type"] as! String)




            }
            messages.reverse()
            titles.reverse()
            usernames.reverse()
            types.reverse()
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you print out `messages` ?

Comment: Should I print it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method or the view did appear method?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` and cellForRowAtIndexPath also

Comment: This is the log I got...                                                                                                                       [This is the message]
[This is the message, This is another message]
[This is the message, This is another message, This is another, other message]
[This is the message, This is another message, This is another, other message]
[This is the message, This is another message, This is another, other message]

Comment: The log is before `messages.reverse()` ? right? call it after `messages.reverse()` in `viewDidAppear `

Comment: I did call it after but for some reason it didn't reverse.

Comment: I think the problem with reverse() method. Can you try `messages = messages.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects`?

Comment: I just tried that and it says that it doesn't contain that member.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out what I did was I did this instead of append...

```
self.messages.insert(object["message"] as! String, atIndex: 0)
```

What this basically does is appends the newest message to the beginning of the array.